# XSD associations by id reference rather than value?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I'm new to XML Schema Definitions. Please look at my XSDs:

Author.xsd :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" 
targetNamespace="http://NamespaceTest.com/AuthorType"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element id="author" name="author" type="AuthorType"/>
<xs:complexType name="AuthorType">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="PersonType">
            <xs:sequence>

            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Book.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified"
targetNamespace="http://NamespaceTest.com/BookType"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:include schemaLocation="http://NamespaceTest.com/AuthorType"/>
<xs:include schemaLocation="http://NamespaceTest.com/ReaderType"/>
<xs:complexType name="BookType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="date" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="author" type="AuthorType" />
        <xs:element name="reader" type="ReaderType"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:int"/>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

In `BookType`, I want to have the `id` of author and the `id` of reader. In this state I have a full `author` and `reader` details, when I need only their ids.

Answer (score 0):

It helps to look at the XML level.

Currently, you're associating `book` with `author` by including an `author` element within the `book` element:

```
<book>
  <name>John</name>
  <date>2018-07-12</date>
  <author id="a1">
    <!-- author elements -->
  </author>
</book>
```

Instead, you'd like to merely reference an `author` by its id:

```
<book>
  <name>John</name>
  <date>2018-07-12</date>
  <author idref="a1"/>
</book>
```

This is the scenario supported by basic XML identifiers and identifier references (in XSD: `xs:ID` and `xs:IDREF`).  Change your `id` attributes to be of type `xs:ID` and your referring attributes to be of type `xs:IDREF`.

**Notes:**

- XML id's must start with a namestart character (which excludes numbers).
- Alternatively, you can use `xs:type` or `xs:token` for your id's and enforce
  uniqueness separately via `xs:unique`.
- XSD also offers `xs:key`/`xs:keyref` as a more flexible alternative to identity reference beyond the
  traditional XML/DTD `id`/`idref` mechanism.